# How to cache get requests for a specific time?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

how can I use Angular HttpInterceptor to cache get requests for a time period? I want to get response from cache before it goes to server.

For example:

1. first request gets data from server
2. cache the response for 60 seconds
3. second request gets data from cache
4. if third request is after 60 seconds get data from server else cache

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
     userDetails: any;
     constructor(public router: Router) { }

     intercept(
       request: HttpRequest<any>,
       next: HttpHandler
     ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

       if (!request.url.includes('auth/login') && this.userDetails) {
         // TODO: If no internet connectivity logout from the session
         // For multi tenancy tenant ID is in auth token so no need to pass extra param just pass auth token
         request = request.clone({
           setHeaders: {
             'x-access-token': CommonUtils.getCookie('token')
           }
         });
       }

       return next.handle(request).pipe(
         map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
           return event;
         }),
         catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
           let data = {};
           data = {
             reason: error ? error : '',
             status: error.status
           };
           return throwError(error);
         })
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: It would be helpful to share what you have tried

Comment: I just created a HttpInterceptor to append `x-access-token` header for every request, so I want know is there any possible way to cache requests by using HttpInterceptor

Comment: Kindly share the code for the interceptor

Comment: updated the question, please check

Answer (score 0):

you can use in that case **publishReplay** to cache data from http calls and you can provide a second parameter **windowtime** in ms, ***the cache will be invalid after this time***

```
  httpCall.pipe(
    publishReplay(1, 60000), // cache will be invalid after 60 seconds
    refCount()
  )
```